# ¿Qué es lo que está mal con mi código para PhpSpreadsheet con php?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

**Code:**

```
use LibreriaCrearExcel\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidation;
use LibreriaCrearExcel\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use LibreriaCrearExcel\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
```

> **Fatal error:** Class 'LibreriaCrearExcel\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\provision\CrearExcel.php on line 18

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: deberías poner tu código en forma de texto, no en imagen.

Comment: ¿Tu librería `PHPSpreassheet` está actualizada a su última versión?

Comment: @RandallSandoval el código está arriba escrito, solo con esas lineas de código me tira el error.

Comment: @A.Cedano si está en la ultima versión.

Answer (score -1):

Te hace falta agregar una linea:

```
require_once '../vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/Bootstrap.php';
```

En tú caso:
require_once '../LibreriaCrearExcel/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/Bootstrap.php';

La carpeta vendor es una carpeta que se genera al instalar PHPspreadSheet con Composer, en tu caso deberias seguir la segunda linea, el archivo Bootstrap.php contiene los archivos autoload que cargaran todas las clases que necesitas ;)

Comment: agrega una explicación por favor, mejoras tu contenido y evitas votos negativos